# Django get substr in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to get substr of request.path and to compare with another variable in templatetag like this, but it doesn't work, I always go to the 'else' branch in this if clause

```
{% if request.path|cut:'/urlpath/' ==  request.var %}
```

Can anyone tell how to use this thing correctly?

Comment: try doing {{request.path|cut:'/urlpath/'}} and {{request.var}} to see what results you are getting.  Might be easier to create your own filter tag

Comment: Since you have both these attributes in the django view, why not compare it there, and send a boolean in the context? Also, you might want to see what the value of `request.path` is - it might not be what you think it is.

Comment: What do you really want to do? Conditioning some work with a URI looks like a bad idea. What if you decide to change your URL patterns? What if your URL patterns contains something like `/urlpath/foo/(?P<slug>[a-z]+)/` and it happens that there is a case where slug = "urlpath"?